# Relation between ΔH and ΔE for the reaction in gaseous phase at constant temperature and pressure

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, enthalpy

> Which of the following statements is correct for the reaction at constant temperature and pressure:
>
> $$\ce{CO(g) + \frac{1}{2}O_2(g) -> CO2(g)}$$
>
> 1. $\Delta H = \Delta E$
> 2. $\Delta H > \Delta E$
> 3. $\Delta H < \Delta E$
> 4. None of these.

Since this occurs at constant temperature, $\Delta E = 0$ and $W < 0$. So, $\Delta H$ turns out to be less than $\Delta E$, but this is not the answer. Why?

Comment: Constant T says nothing about delta E or delta H., as the system is not isolated.

Comment: Constant temperature does not make the change in energy zero

Comment: For a chemically reacting system (or a single component change of phase), the internal energy of the system changes even if the temperature does not.

Comment: Wanted to confirm if $\Delta E$ represents internal energy. Sorry, I'm not used to this notation (I've always used $\Delta U$ as internal energy).

Answer (score 2):

By definition, $$\Delta H=\Delta E+\Delta(PV)$$For a reacting ideal gas mixture at constant temperature, $$\Delta(PV)=(\Delta n)RT$$where $\Delta n$ is the change in the number of moles between reactants and products.  Therefore, $$\Delta H=\Delta E+(\Delta n)RT$$For the reaction under consideration, $$\Delta n=-\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\Delta H=\Delta E + p \cdot \Delta V$$

$\Delta E$ is energy change of a system at constant volume.

$\Delta H$ as is energy change of a system at constant pressure.

As the molar amount of gases is decreased by the reaction, $p \cdot \Delta V \lt 0$ at constant $T,p$.

Therefore, $\Delta H \lt \Delta E$

Neither that $\Delta E<0$ even at constant $T$, as energy released by the combustion reaction is dissipated in the system surrounding.